# How to access controls from aspx file in other .cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

I have a aspx file where controls are written. I want to access these controls in .cs file which is not code of this aspx file but another class file.

For example: I want to update an UpdatePanel from another .cs file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it as a parameter to the method in the other class file. Something like:

```
public class OtherClassFile
{
    public static void UpdateMethod(UpdatePanel panel)
    {
        //Update the panel here
    }
}
```

Then the methdod call in your .aspx page would look like this:

```
OtherClassFile.UpdateMethod(MyUpdatePanel);
```

Comment: Actually I don't wish to pass it as a parameter, is there any other way?

Comment: @DKR Not that I am aware of. Why do you not want to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: @ that is because those methods are created dynamically